# 32 bits data transfer from Pi to FPGA using spidev

Tags: pi-3

I'm trying to 32 bits data send and receive between Pi and FPGA using spi. So, I set the Pi as master and FPGA as slave. And use xfer2 function from spidev. But, I couldn't read data. How can I fix it?.

First 4 bytes for deciding read or write cycle. And last 4 bytes are the data to transfer to FPGA.
For example, if the first 4 bytes are 0x00000000, then this is write cycle. And, last 4 bytes are transferred to FPGA. So, I want to send data by using xfer2. like this, xfer2([0x00000000, 0x000000ff]). But, it didn't work. So, I thought that xfer2 only transfer data 1-byte per. And, I changed it to xfer2([0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff]).

And, whatever data I sent, this code just printed out [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0].

My simple spi test code is below.

```py
import spidev
import time

spi=spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0,1)
spi.max_speed_hz= 190000000 

while True:

    resp = spi.xfer2([0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00]) # read
    print(resp)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    spi.xfer2([0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff]) # write
    time.sleep(0.1)

    resp = spi.xfer2([0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00]) # read
    print(resp)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    spi.xfer2([0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01]) # write
    time.sleep(0.1)

    resp = spi.xfer2([0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00]) # read  
    print(resp)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    resp1 = spi.xfer2([0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02]) # write
    time.sleep(0.1)
    
    resp = spi.xfer2([0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00]) # read
    print(resp)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    resp1 = spi.xfer2([0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04]) # write
    time.sleep(0.1)
    
    resp = spi.xfer2([0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00]) # read
    print(resp)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    resp1 = spi.xfer2([0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08]) # write
    time.sleep(0.1)
    
    resp = spi.xfer2([0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00]) # read
    print(resp)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    resp1 = spi.xfer2([0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x10]) # write
    time.sleep(0.1)
    
    resp = spi.xfer2([0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00]) # read
    print(resp)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    resp1 = spi.xfer2([0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x20]) # write
    time.sleep(0.1)
    
    resp = spi.xfer2([0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00]) # read
    print(resp)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    resp1 = spi.xfer2([0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x40]) # write
    time.sleep(0.1)
    
    resp = spi.xfer2([0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00]) # read
    print(resp)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    resp1 = spi.xfer2([0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80]) # write
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

This is the results

[image]

Comment: Please add clear photos of the connections.  Please edit your question and clarify the data rate you plan to use as there is a discrepancy between the set speed and the comments.

Comment: Thank you joan. I clarify the question.

Comment: I think the maximum SPI speed supported by the hardware is 125MHz.  I doubt that the Pi can reliably transfer at that rate.

Comment: I tested lower frequency like 500kHz. But, I couldn't print the dataset even though data was transferred and controlled the LED. I want to print out the data from read cycle to check whether the data was well tranferred.

Comment: Please edit your question and show what is printed.

Comment: Thnak you again. Whatever data I sent, this code just printed out [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0].

Comment: Need those  photos.

Comment: I added the photo on the question text

Comment: This begs the question that the FPGA is working the way you think it is.  Have you verified that independently?  Using a scope (hardware or software) would be good.

Comment: I think FPGA is working well. Because when I transfered the data to control a specific LED, then that LED was on. And, I could print out when I sent 8 bits data. So, I don't know why it didn't print out when 32 bits transfer.

Comment: We need photos of the connections you have made between the Pi and the FPGA.  We need to be able to trace pin to pin.